# How do I access HTTP event body in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular File upload in my code. I'm using a HTTP Event to track the progress of file upload. After that, I want to map the data received from the response to an interface but I'm not able to access the body of the response.

This is my code to track the progress of upload and get the body of the response :

```
public async UploadRcptList() {
    for (const droppedFile of this.fileUploadManager) {

      // Is it a file?
      if (droppedFile.file.fileEntry.isFile) {
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.file.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;

        fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
          this.Uploader.recipientUpload(file, this.chosenValue).subscribe(
            event => {
              if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                this.fileUploadManager[0].progress = ((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
              }
              if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                console.log(event);
                console.log("We have response:" + event.body);
                this.Uploader.setLists(event.body as Mixed);
                //if(count ==1)
                this.emptyFilesArray()
                //else count--;
              }
            }
          )
        });
      }

      else {
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.file.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
        console.log(droppedFile.file.relativePath, fileEntry);
      }
    }
```

Here, when I try to log event, I get the whole response which is a JSON that looks something like this :

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "attachmentList": [
            {
               ...
            }
        ],
        "recipientList": [
            {
                ...
            },
        ]
    },
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

However when I try to log event.body, I get [object Object]. How can I access the "data" attribute inside the response body?

This is my code for the service :

```
public recipientUpload(file: File, type: string) {
    const details = {
       ...
    }
    formData.append('reqjson', JSON.stringify(details))
    formData.append('file', file);

    return this.http.request(new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://xyz.abc/fileUpload', formData, { reportProgress: true }));
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, event.body should give me the whole JSON response, right? I tried accessing event.body.data but I got an error saying data does not exist on event.body. How can I access that "data" attribute on the response?

Answer (score 0):

you can try try with it

```
 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(event);
 console.log(myJSON.yourfield);
```